# How to use grep function in for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I have troubles using the grep function within a for loop.
In my data set, I have several columns where only the last 5-6 letters change. With the loop I want to use the same functions for all 16 situations.

Here is my code:

```
situations <- c("KKKTS", "KKKNL", "KKDTS", "KKDNL", "NkKKTS", "NkKKNL", "NkKDTS", "NkKDNL", "KTKTS", "KTKNL", "KTDTS", "KTDNL", "NkTKTS", "NkTKNL", "NkTDTS", "NkTDNL")
View(situations)

for (i in situations[1:16]) {
  
  ## Trust Skala
  a <- vector("numeric", length = 1L)
  b <- vector("numeric", length = 1L)
  a <- grep("Tru_1_[i]", colnames(cleandata))
  b <- grep("Tru_5_[i]", colnames(cleandata))
  cleandata[, c(a:b)] <- 8-cleandata[, c(a:b)]
  
  attach(cleandata)
  cleandata$scale_tru_[i] <- (Tru_1_[i] + Tru_2_[i] + Tru_3_[i] + Tru_4_[i] + Tru_5_[i])/5
  detach(cleandata)
}
```

With the grep function I first want to finde the column number of e.g. Tru_1_KKKTS and Tru_5_KKKTS. Then I want to reverse code the items of the specific column numbers. The last part worked without the loop when I manually used grep for every single situation.

Here ist the manual version:

```
# KKKTS
grep("Tru_1_KKKTS", colnames(cleandata)) #29 -> find the index of respective column
grep("Tru_5_KKKTS", colnames(cleandata)) #33
cleandata[,c(29:33)] <- 8-cleandata[c(29:33)] # trust scale ranges from 1 to 7 [8-1/2/3/4/5/6/7 = 7/6/5/4/3/2/1]

attach(cleandata)
cleandata$scale_tru_KKKTS <- (Tru_1_KKKTS + Tru_2_KKKTS + Tru_3_KKKTS + Tru_4_KKKTS + Tru_5_KKKTS)/5
detach(cleandata)
```

Comment: `attach()` is dangerous; do not use it!

Comment: I don't get the ` # trust scale ranges from 1 to 7 [8-1/2/3/4/5/6/7 = 7/6/5/4/3/2/1]` how does that relate to column 29 to 33?

Comment: ah it is just some range (values of columns ...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about something like this. It's a bit more compact and you don't have to use `attach`..

```
situations <- c("KKKTS", "KKKNL", "KKDTS", "KKDNL", "NkKKTS", "NkKKNL", "NkKDTS", "NkKDNL", "KTKTS", "KTKNL", "KTDTS", "KTDNL", "NkTKTS", "NkTKNL", "NkTDTS", "NkTDNL")

for (i in situations[1:16]) {

    cols   <- paste("Tru",   1:5, i, sep = "_")
    result <- paste("scale_tru" , i, sep = "_")
    
    cleandata[cols] <- 8 - cleandata[cols]
    cleandata[result] <- rowMeans(cleandata[cols])
    
}
```

I took for granted that when you write `a:b` you mean all the columns between those, which I assumed were named from 2 to 4

Comment: My bad, thanks a lot for your help. Your solution worked well.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
Mean5 <- function(sit) {
  cnames <- paste0("Tru_", 1:5, "_", sit)
  rowMeans(cleandata[cnames])
}

cleandata[, paste0("scale_tru_", situations)] <- sapply(situations, FUN=Mean5)
```

Comment: great solution! just you're missing a `]` in the last row and `cnames` should be defined this way: `paste("Tru", 1:5, sit, sep = "_")` :)

Answer (score 0):

```
situations <- c("KKKTS", "KKKNL", "KKDTS", "KKDNL", "NkKKTS", "NkKKNL", "NkKDTS", "NkKDNL", "KTKTS", "KTKNL", "KTDTS", "KTDNL", "NkTKTS", "NkTKNL", "NkTDTS", "NkTDNL")

# constructor for column names
get_col_names <- function(part) paste("Tru", 1:5, part, sep="_")

for (situation in situtations) {
  # revert the values in the columns in situ
  cleandata[, get_col_names(situation)] <- 8 - cleandata[, get_col_names(situtation)]
  # and calculate the average
  subdf <- cleandata[, get_col_names(situation)]
  cleandata[, paste0("scale_tru_", situation)] <- rowSums(subdf)/ncol(subdf)
}
```

By the way, you call it "scale" but your code shows an average/mean calculation.
(Scale without centering).

Comment: `cleandata[, paste0(scale_tru_, s) ] <-` missing a `]` there :)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Yes, first I reverse code the scale (because some items have a negative connotation), and after I calculate the scale score. So scale does not refere to centering but to a scale of items. :)